# Getting object reference error on a base.Method() in release mode

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I'm using **Eyeshot 12** to render a 3D Model for my app. The model works fine in debug mode, but throws an object reference error if I try to zoom in on the model **using the mouse wheel** in release mode.
This is my model so far (using try-catch to stop the app from crashing suddenly):

```
public class Model3D : devDept.Eyeshot.Model
{
  protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
      base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

The error is this:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: *What can I do to fix this problem?* Check if its Null (first determine if its `base` or `e`).

Comment: @JeremyThompson `e` is not null and c# doesn't let you check if `base` is null (of course you can't, it's not an instance)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out what was causing the error, but I fixed it by overriding `OnMouseWheel` and writing my own logic, like this:

```
public class Model3D : devDept.Eyeshot.Model
{
  protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
  {
    ZoomCamera(new System.Drawing.Point((int)e.GetPosition(this).X, (int)e.GetPosition(this).Y), e.Delta, false);
    Invalidate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this before when you can't instantiate, use a Nullable type or etc, and this is difficult because its a bug with the 3rd party product. Can you try `if (base.GetType() == typeof(BaseClass))`

Since `GetType` is a method of `object` (the core reference type) its always available, regardless of whether the derived object has been instantiated or not.